# Ajax not working in JSF

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I don't know why Ajax is not working in my JSF files.Even I have a latest Mojarra which is 3.2.13 in my GlassFish. Here is my code

```
<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:panelGroup id="panel" rendered="#{chartBean.showCharts}">

            <p:barChart id="basic" value="#{chartBean.categoryModel}"
            legendPosition="ne" title="Basic Bar Chart" min="0" max="200"
            style="height:300px" />

    </h:panelGroup>

    <h:commandButton value="Display Chart" action="#{chartBean.createCategoryModel}">
    <f:ajax render="panel"/>
    </h:commandButton>
</h:body>
```

Now when I run this code, button doesn't work.

Another thing, if I change my code like remove panel and just render on barchart like 
`<f:ajax render="basic"/>` and placed it in `<form>` 
then it throws `NullPointerException`. Because it render the chart and expect value from `chartBean.categoryModel`. Now AFAIK it should not be rendered because of ajax.

I am unable to understand ajax behavior in JSF. I also tried `<f:ajax execute="@form" render="basic">` but it didn't work too. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: William, Ajax4jsf is a sublibrary of RichFaces with taglib URI `http://richfaces.org/a4j` and `a4j:` prefix. Please don't use `[ajax4jsf]` tag on the question if you are actually not using it.

Comment: @khan: please do not format non-code as code! Also, your suggested edit was poor as it didn't address all issues in the post, it should have been rejected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot re-render a component that is not there on your page at the time you click the ajax button.

A simple solution would be to move the rendered attribute from the `h:panelGroup` to the `p:barChart`. Then the panelGroup will always be rendered and JSF finds it during your ajax request.

```
<h:panelGroup id="panel">

        <p:barChart rendered="#{chartBean.showCharts}"
                    id="basic" value="#{chartBean.categoryModel}"
                    legendPosition="ne" title="Basic Bar Chart" min="0" max="200"
                    style="height:300px" />
</h:panelGroup>

<h:commandButton value="Display Chart" action="#{chartBean.createCategoryModel}">
<f:ajax render="panel"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

Comment: thanks it is working :) but i want to a little about ajax behavior in JSF.What about "execute" attribute and "render"..

Comment: The `execute` attribute determines which components will be processed on the server (converted, validated, assigned to model values). The `render` attribute skips these processing steps an only re-renders the component.